# How to send .docx and .rtf file to "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pdf, printing

I want to print exising docx or rtf file to the build-on "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer.
I have a simple Delphi code:

```
uses
  Printers;

procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DeviceMode: THandle;
  Device, Driver, Port: array[0..80] of Char;
  Printer: TPrinter;
begin
  Printer.PrinterIndex := Printer.Printers.IndexOf('Microsoft Print to PDF');
  Printer.GetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, DeviceMode);
  Printer.SetPrinter(Device, Driver, 'C:\Temp\Test.pdf', 0);
  Printer.BeginDoc;
  ......... I can use canvas to print simple texts BUT.....
  .........? how to print an existing docx or rtf file ?....
  Printer.EndDoc;
end;
```

Comment: The difficult part is the `docx` part. You need Microsoft Word or some other software to print such files. Use OLE to automate Microsoft Word, if installed on the system.

Comment: So if I understand correctly when I print a docx file "the magic" is in the MSWord itself, not in the printer. Same for rtf I guess.
I see.

Answer (score 1):

You can only "print" what the TCanvas class support. And unfortunaley, it does not support rendering docx nor rtf documents.

You can print RTF or DOCX *files* by invoking ShellExecute with the command 'print'. This will start the associated application requesting it to print the document file you pass.

Or (Better control) you can use the WORD component provided with Delphi (Not installed by default) to automate Word, make it load and print the RTF or DOCX document. You can also automate your own rendering into the document provided it is possible to do it with Word (And chances are big that it is the case).

Long time ago I write a blog post about printing with Word from a Delphi application. See http://francois-piette.blogspot.com/2014/02/automate-word-document-print-using.html

Comment: Yes, automation is not a problem to implement.
I'm wondering myself to my guess that "Microsoft Print to PDF" does the trick :) I just missed that it uses TCanvas, and nothing more.

I need to print to .pdf without installed word application so automation is not an option.
Obviously I'll need some external library or component to use in my delphi application.

Comment: "Obviously I'll need some external library or component to use in my Delphi application." As far as I know, there is no library that implement all the features of Word DOCX file format. Some free software implement a more or less complete subset. Last time I checked one, it lost a number of things.